# Android Emulator warning and low performance after updating to MacOS High Sierra

Tags: android-emulator, macos-high-sierra

Whenever I start the emulator I get this warning

Your GPU driver information:

> GPU #1
>     Make: 8086
>     Model: 0166
>     Device ID: 0166
>
> Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version.  As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer.  Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver  available.

Also the emulator is slow to the point its almost unusable.
I am running MacOS High Sierra on Mid 2012 MacBookPro with 10GB ram and 250GB SSD.My Intel HAXM installation is on point.

Sidenote: Additionally I tried to run the genymotion emulator but with no luck speed improvement.

Comment: Hey, have you managed to find a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: not yet. I am using a physical device to debug my android code for now.

Comment: Any update? Also, is this a Retina machine with the nVidia GPU? If so, is your GPU still working? Having similar issues but they only started _after_ I "upgraded"  to the latest emulator (27.2.9)

Answer (score 3):

If you running the android emulator on MacOS, go to ~/.android/ folder and delete the following files:
"emu-last-feature-flags.protobuf"
and
"emu-update-last-check.ini"

then run the emulator again. My laptop has Intel HD4000 and I solve the problem in this way.

Comment: This did not work for me on a mid-2012 MBP running Catalina